# Copy application config file to another application directory

Tags: unit-testing, build, app-config

I am testing a WCF service, which is hosted in a console application. I am running the test using NUnit. So I want to copy the console application and app.config of console application to the Bin\Debug folder of the Test assembly. I am able to copy the console application, by adding the reference to the test assembly, but app.config of console application is not coming. Also I tried to copy by setting the properties, it not worked. It is copying the app.config as it is, it not changing the name as ConsoleApp.exe.Config. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a post build event to do this, which will copy the projects app.config and will rename it ConsoleApp.exe.config.

You could also just create a file in your project called ConsoleApp.exe.config and fill it with the config required for the tests and have it copy to the output directory.  this would be my preferred solution as it would mean that the tests would be in control of the config and would not be affected by the potential changes to the app.config in the console applications project.

Comment: Hmm I agree to this approch. But its a big project and my manager didn't like the concept of Pre/Post build events.

Comment: @Anuraj if you create your own config file in the test project then you don't need the post build step.  this is the better solution in my opinion.